# What is a common-lisp analogue of python's argparse?

Tags: python, common-lisp, argparse

What is a common-lisp analogue of python's argparse library for parsing command-line arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few including:

command-line-arguments -- http://cliki.net/command-line-arguments

getopt -- https://github.com/keithj/getopt

unix-options -- https://github.com/astine/unix-options

I haven't actually tried any of them but hopefully one of them fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `apply-argv` for our bundle-generator.